# How to delete sites showing up in backend of Aquia Dev Desktop

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

Deleted sites still showing up with Aquia Dev Desktop even if I already deleted files and databases.

Any way to clear these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, at the bottom left of the window there is a + and - sign, they look like sorting icons,but actually they are to delete. Clicking on minus does it.